# why Popen can't exec python cmd?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I want to exec command using Popen, see my code below:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/python a.py')
p2 = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
print p2.stdout.readlines()
```

while I exec this script, I get the error below:

```
File "demo.py", line 4, in <module>
  p0 = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/python a.py')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
 errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What's the problem? 
Another question is what if a.py is a 'while-True-loop' can p2 return?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/python a.py', shell=True)` or `subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/python', 'a.py'])`.

Answer (score 4):

Check your python and your "a.py" script path and make sure they exist!

After that try this :

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/python" , "a.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

good luck!